# Port not being released on server shutdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, unicorn

Whenever I shut down my development server (unicorn), the port 8080 does not get released until I close Terminal and reload it from start.

```
→ unicorn_rails
I, [2012-06-09T09:56:05.919307 #6635]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8080 fd=3
I, [2012-06-09T09:56:05.919716 #6635]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2012-06-09T09:56:05.921280 #6635]  INFO -- : master process ready
I, [2012-06-09T09:56:05.923884 #6636]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=6636
I, [2012-06-09T09:56:05.924617 #6636]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2012-06-09T09:56:35.156762 #6636]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
I, [2012-06-09T10:12:01.217846 #6635]  INFO -- : SIGWINCH ignored because we're not daemonized
^Z
[3]+  Stopped                 unicorn_rails
```

When I try to restart

```
→ unicorn_rails
E, [2012-06-09T11:48:24.172525 #9741] ERROR -- : adding listener failed addr=0.0.0.0:8080 (in use)
E, [2012-06-09T11:48:24.172783 #9741] ERROR -- : retrying in 0.5 seconds (4 tries left)
```

I shut down the server with Control Z

Am I using wrong command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes ctrl-z sends it to a background job.  To shut it down, use ctrl-c.

Answer (score 1):

If you have sent it to a background job, you can use `fg` to return it to the foreground, or look for it's process id, using `ps`, and then kill it using `kill -9 <pid>` (where `<pid>` is the process id found earlier).